# How do I set specific "after login options " that depend on login credentials?

Tags: c#

Hi I have a Windows Form Application and need to open different Pages depending on the Login Credentials provided. If Administrator Credentials are provided (i.e Username= Administrator) then a Window Form Application called "AdminPage" should be called Up. Else a Window Form Application called "Main_Page" should.

My code gives me the message "A DataReader associated to this command is still open. It must be closed first."

This is my code;

```
try
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PV10\\LOCALSERVER;Initial Catalog=SmallSoftwareDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserCredentials where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", cn);
                SqlDataReader dr;
                cn.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int cnt = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
                if (cnt == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successful Login...", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    string query = "select Username, Password from UserCredentials where Username='Administrator";
                    SqlCommand cmdA = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                    dr = cmdA.ExecuteReader();
                    int k = 0;
                    while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        k++;
                    }
                    if(k == 1)
                    {
                        AdminPage A_P = new AdminPage();
                        A_P.Tag = this;
                        A_P.Show(this);
                        Hide();
                    }
                    Main_Page Mp = new Main_Page();
                    Mp.Tag = this;
                    Mp.Show(this);
                    Hide();
                    cn.Close();
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName or Password", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL Injection, put a `'` in the textboxes and see what happens.  Use a parameterized query instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
```

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PV10\LOCALSERVER;Initial Catalog=SmallSoftwareDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"); con.Open(); string Lg = "SELECT Username, Password FROM UserCredentials where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'"; SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Lg, con); SqlDataReader dr; dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); int t = 0; while (dr.Read()) { t++; } if (t == 1) { MessageBox.Show("Successful Login", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); ) { AdminPage Ap = new AdminPage(); Ap.Tag = this; Ap.Show(this); textBox1.Clear(); textBox2.Clear(); Hide(); } else { Main_Page Mp = new Main_Page(); Mp.Tag = this; Mp.Show(this); textBox1.Clear(); textBox2.Clear(); Hide(); } } else { MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password", " ", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop); textBox1.Clear(); textBox2.Clear(); } } catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, " ", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); } }